# Traefik with gRPC and Let's Encrypt?

Tags: docker, grpc, lets-encrypt, traefik

I followed the Traefik guide to setting up [Let's Encrypt and Docker](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/docker-and-lets-encrypt/), and now `my-domain.com` properly accepts HTTPS with a static website behind it. Next I'd like to get a gRPC server running behind Traefik at `my-grpc-server.my-domain.com`. Looking at the Traefik documentation for using [gRPC with Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/grpc/), I see that the instructions are to use self-signed certificates. How do I take advantage of the fact that I already have valid certificates from Let's Encrypt?

Taking a stab at a solution... in my `grpc-server` Docker container, I could maybe mount the `acme.json` file that Traefik writes, read the keys from that file, and use them to initialize the gRPC server. That'd require some grunt work, which is fine, but even then it seems like I'd maybe still need a different `traefik.toml` configuration to account for the fact that the traffic between Traefik and my `grpc-server` Docker container need SSL.

---

UPDATE: I've been giving this a try with no success so far. I manually exported the acme keys for testing this so as to get the Let's Encrypt stuff out of the picture for simplicity's sake.

Here's the gRPC client error:
`grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.CANCELLED, Received http2 header with status: 500)>`

And the Traefik error:
`level=warning msg="Error forwarding to https://172.18.0.2:443, err: stream error: stream ID 1; INTERNAL_ERROR"`

Curiously, when I connect with the gRPC client, there is no message on the gRPC server. However, when I hit `my-grpc-server.my-server.com` in a *web browser* I get the same error in Traefik and an additional error on the gRPC server:
`E1112 21:06:37.480636928       8 http_server_filter.c:236]   GET request without QUERY`
I'm wondering now why the traffic gets forwarded in the web browser case but not the gRPC client case.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate in https between your traefik and your container, you need to add the label traefik.protocol=https on your container (https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers)

Moreover, with the docker backend when traefik will contact your backend server, it will use the IP of the container (and it doesn't match your domain certificate). So you may can active  `InsecureSkipVerify` in your traefik configuration (https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/commons/#main-section).

Comment: Would it be possible to use Let's Encrypt between the client and `my-grpc-server.my-domain.com`, then use self-signed certificates for the traffic between Traefik and the gRPC server itself? That way it could be encrypted the whole way.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this one. I have enabled `InsecureSkipVerify = true` in my traefik.toml file, but I get `Error forwarding to https://172.18.0.4:50051, err: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake`.

Comment: Would it be possible to use Let's Encrypt ? No (not with docker backend).


Are you sure you have activate the HTTPS on your gRpc client and on your gRpc Server ?